# How to import data for fluid simulation?

Tags: import, file-format, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to import in Blender some fluid simulations, created externally with other programs (e.g. Fortran..), in order to give a 3D feedback to the estimated data. I know that it's possible to do and that it's very easy too.

Anyone can suggest me any solution??

Comment: What external program(s) are you using for the fluid simulation? What file formats do those external programs offer to save the 3D model of the fluid?

Comment: You might want to look at what has been done with dualSPHysics. See https://blenderyard.wordpress.com/2014/12/28/dualsphysics-fluid-visualization-with-blender/ , http://dual.sphysics.org/vanilla/discussion/522/dsph-to-blender-pipeline/p1 ,  and https://wiki.manchester.ac.uk/sphysics/images/Blender_for_SPHysics_v2.2_GUIDE.pdf .